# PHP - Populating a multidimensionnal array

Tags: php, arrays

I wish to populate an array with continents, countries and areas. The result would look like that:

```
$arr_continent = array( 
  '7' => array (
    'name' => 'Africa',
    'countries' => array (
      'CG' => array(
        'name' => 'Congo',
        'areas' => array('a', 'b', 'c')),
      'ZF' => array(
        'name' => 'South Africa')
        'areas' => array('a', 'b', 'c')),
    )
  ),
  '2' => array (
    'name' => 'North Amercia',
    'countries' => array (
      'US' => array(
...
```

I loop through countries to populate the array (or at least I'm trying to) with:

```
foreach ($countries as $country) {
  $arr_continent[$country->continent_id] = array(
    'name' => $country->name,
    'countries' => array());

  $arr_continents[$country->continent_id]['countries'][$country->id] = array(
    'name' => $country->name,
    ...);
}
```

But I can't make it work. I also tried to test if the continent_id key was not already in the array but that didn't work either `if (! array_key_exists($country->continent_id, $arr_continent)) {`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thank you

Comment: Right direction: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php! %)P

Comment: your example seems to have country ids as 2 letters, yet in the code you use $country->id, is it a number or 2 letters?

Comment: You need help creating an array in desired format, yet you don't provide input data format. So I can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be quite simple

```
foreach ($countries as $country) {

    // init a new continent
    if (!isset($arr_continent[$country->continent_id])) {
        $arr_continent[$country->continent_id] = array(
            'name' => $country->continent_name,
            'countries' => array()
        );
    }

    // adding the country
    $arr_continent[$country->continent_id]['countries'][$country->id] = array(
        'name' => $country->name
        'areas' => ...
    );

}
```

First you init a new continent if needed. You set the name and create an empty country array. Then you add the country to this array.

Comment: It works, I missed the `isset` method, thank you DerVO